# Variable initialization using is operator gives error when using same variable name

Tags: c#, scope, operators, c#-7.0

I am using the C# 7.0 syntax to initialize a variable when checking the type using the `is` operator. I want to use the same variable name, say "animal", for all scenarios, like this:

```
// Yes, polymorphism may be better. This is just an illustration.
if (item is Dog animal) { // ... }
else if (item is Cat animal) { // ... }
else if (item is Animal animal) { // ... }
else { // ... }
```

However, I get an error that says the variable name is used in an enclosing scope. Is there a way to get around this? I'd really rather not have to use different variable names for each `else if` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This page](https://www.danielcrabtree.com/blog/152/c-sharp-7-is-operator-patterns-you-wont-need-as-as-often) has a nice explanation of what is going on. Basically, just as the error indicates, the initialized variable is available in the enclosing scope of the `if` and `else if` statements. This is similar to how `out` parameters work. So, yes, when using a series of `if` statements, you may use a variable name only once.

An alternative would be to use a `switch` instead of an `if`:

```
switch (item) {
    case Dog animal:
        // ...
        break;
    case Cat animal:
        // ...
        break;
    case Animal animal:
        // ...
        break;
    default:
        // Interestingly, you cannot reuse the variable name here.
        // But you could create a new scope and then reuse it.
        {
            Animal animal = ...
        }
        break;
}
```

The variables initialized in the `switch` are limited to the scope of their `case`. [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11409859/1089416).