# Strange Behavior of Switch Statements

Tags: c#, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Variable declaration in c# switch statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222601/variable-declaration-in-c-sharp-switch-statement)
>   [What is the purpose of the extra braces in Switch case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095280/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-extra-braces-in-switch-case)

Today I was writing a small piece of code and, at debugging time, VS slapped me and told me I made a big mistake with my local variables names: "A local variable named 'i' is already defined in this scope".

```
MyEnum enumerator = MyEnum.B;

switch (enumerator)
{
    case MyEnum.A:
        Int32 i = 0;
        // DoStuffsA();
        break;

    case MyEnum.B:
        Double i = 0D;
        // DoStuffsB();
        break;
}
```

So I said "Ok VS, let me fix it in a moment, I want to scope my cases first as I like them more!". So I made my cosmetic change... but suddenly VS stopped whining about that error:

```
MyEnum enumerator = MyEnum.B;

switch (enumerator)
{
    case MyEnum.A:
    {
        Int32 i = 0;
        // DoStuffsA();
        break;
    }

    case MyEnum.B:
    {
        Double i = 0D;
        // DoStuffsB();
        break;
    }
}
```

Ok... I'm aware of the meaning of "scope" and I know I produced two different scopes like so. The problem is that I don't know how switch statements are translated into IL code and I always thought that all the case statements were placed into the switch scope no matter if curly braces were used or not. So... the following oddity can be compiled, right?

```
MyEnum enumerator = MyEnum.B;

switch (enumerator)
{
    case MyEnum.A:
        String s = "Hello!";
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        break;

    case MyEnum.B:
        s = "Goodbye!";
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        break;
}
```

But not the following one:

```
MyEnum enumerator = MyEnum.B;

switch (enumerator)
{
    case MyEnum.A:
    {
        String s = "hello";
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        break;
    }

    case MyEnum.B:
    {
        s = "goodbye";
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        break;
    }
}
```

Can some explain me better the behavior of the compiler in this situation?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, the translation to IL is somewhat irrelevant. IL doesn't have the same concepts of scope at all. This is all about the C# language specification.

It's pretty simple, really: the scope of a local variable is the *block* in which it's declared, and you can't declare one local variable when another local variable of the same name is in scope.

- In your first snippet of code, the scope of `i` is the whole switch statement. Your second declaration tries to declare another `i` variable within the same scope, thus it fails.
- In your second snippet of code, the scope of each `i` variable is just the block created by the curly braces - they're in entirely separate scopes, no nesting, so it's fine.
- In your third snippet of code, the variable `s` is in scope for the second case, as its scope is the entire switch statement - so it's fine to use it.
- In your fourth snippet of code, the variable `s` is *only* in the scope of the block in which it's declared (inside case A) so it's not in scope in case B.

I would *strongly* recommend against using code like your third snippet of code though. It will confuse many people. If you really want a variable which is in scope for multiple cases, I'd declare it *before* the switch statement.

Answer (score 6):

When you add the `{}` in the different `case` blocks, you are introducing *scopes*.

Without them, all `case` blocks are within one scope.

With your last two examples, where you use `s` - the first one is fine, as `s` is declared in the `case` for `MyEnum.A` so can be used in `MyEnum.B`, however with the braces, the declaration in `MyEnum.A` is in its own scope, not visible outside - so in `MyEnum.B`, `s` is not known and needs to be declared anew.

Answer (score -1):

Having the `break` inside the braces causes it to break to the end of the brace, at which point your `case` falls through.  You need the `break` statement outside of the braces.  E.g.

```
case MyEnum.A:
{
    String s = "hello";
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
break;
```