# Weird behaviour in XCode

Tags: c, syntax, compiler-errors, case-statement

Just wanted to get your thought on this, I recall reading that property declarations are forbidden inside `switch-case` statements (i.e. `case:ABC int i=0;` is not allowed)

I came across something rather odd this morning,

the following compiles

```
switch(var1) {
  case 1:
    NSLog(@"hello");
    float x = 0;
    view.setCenter(CGPointMake(x,100));
    break;
  ...
```

whereas the following does **NOT** compile

```
switch(var1) {
  case 1:
    float x = 0;
    view.setCenter(CGPointMake(x,100));
    break;
  ...
```

So it seems if you start a `case` expression with a statement (not declaration), it compiles. But when you try to start right away with a variable declaration, it doesn't.

What is the rationale behind this?

EDIT:
Decided to make my question clearer, **what difference does NSLog make** so that it compiles now?

Comment: What compile error do you get?

Comment: @Spectravideo328 You are right and the answer there is much better than mine.

Comment: Thanks all, mystery resolved :) So it's not a compiler bug but it's by definition that a label must be followed by an expression, which is odd (I still haven't seen any good reason why this should be like this)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `NSLog` doesn't make a difference here. It's the `;` that is making the difference:

```
switch(var1) {
    case 1:
        ;
        float x = 0;
        view.setCenter(CGPointMake(x,100));
        break;
```

compiles. Even

```
 switch(var1) {
    case 1:;
        float x = 0;
        view.setCenter(CGPointMake(x,100));
        break;
```

What cannot compile is `float` (or other type) immediately after `:`. In other words, a command is expected after `:`, not a declaration.

Answer (score 0):

It does compile if you:

```
switch(var1) {
  case 1:
  {
    float x = 0;
    view.setCenter(CGPointMake(x,100));
  }
    break;
```

As for the why check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652408/c-sharp-switch-statement-with-without-curly-brackets-whats-the-difference).

Comment: I couldn't find in neither that SO post or the 'four switch oddities' post referred by it. My question is what difference does NSLog make