# Can not get it to accept a "letter" input

Tags: java

Forgive me I am new to programming, but thoroughly enjoy what I have learned so far. So my question is; I am trying to write a program  that prompts the user to enter a letter, then returns whether the letter is a vowel or a consonant. Problem is I can not get it to accept a letter input. It will accept it if forced to as in "user_input = 'a'". But not as an option. I know  am missing something simple.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int user_input;

    System.out.print("Enter a letter: ");
    user_input = in.nextInt();//<--line of error

    if (user_input == 'a')
    {
        System.out.println("Vowel");
    }
    else if (user_input =='e')
    {
        System.out.println("Vowel");
    }
    else if (user_input =='i')
    {
        System.out.println("Vowel");
    }
    else if (user_input =='o')
    {
        System.out.println("Vowel");
    }
    else if (user_input =='u')
    {
        System.out.println("Vowel");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Consonant");
    }
}
```

Thank you ahead of time for your time.

Comment: See Scanner.next() - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're reading a character, you should use the character type.  additionally, you'd want to read the next character, not the next int.  `.next()` will read the next string, then `charAt(0)` gets just the first character.

```
System.out.print("Enter a letter: ");
char user_input = in.next().charAt(0);
```

And if you want to be case insensitive:

```
char user_input = in.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
```

You could also stand to reduce the repetition of the code by using a logical "or" instead of separate `if`s

```
if (user_input == 'a'
 || user_input =='e'
 || user_input =='i'
 || user_input =='o'
 || user_input =='u')
{
    System.out.println("Vowel");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Consonant");
}
```

However, you may prefer the `switch` syntax approach

```
switch (user_input) {
    case 'a':
    case 'e':
    case 'i':
    case 'o':
    case 'u':
        System.out.println("Vowel");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Consonant");
        break;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, OP could use a switch statement like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16706729/3703709)

Comment: @mstbaum you'd prefer setting a variable rather than setting in the case as I have?  I'm not quite sure I understand what you're suggesting differently

Comment: I think I skipped over your switch syntax part that you already provided and just didn't notice it. My bad.

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you. It worked and i added a error message in case something else was entered (like more then one letter or a number).