# is it possible to use the multiple cases in "if condition" to access the same function

Tags: java, switch-statement

I need to access the same function for all the cases so I implemented the multiple cases in the if condition. as IDE Throws an error for this, it is obvious that this is the wrong implementation. But is there something which can be an alternative to such logic.

> java

```
 void movie() {
                int m;
                System.out.println("Choose the movie :");
                System.out.println("1.BAHUBALI\n2.SHIVAAY\n3.DANGAL\n4.AIRLIFT");
                m =sc.nextInt();
          switch(m){
                if(case 1: || case 2: || case 3: || case 4:) {
                     Payment();
                }

                else {
                    System.out.println("Choosen an Invlid option");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do take a look at rephrased [switch labels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52238221/1746118)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:-

```
switch (key) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4: 
            Payment();
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Choosen an Invlid option");
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing `Integer` comparison here, you could use `Map` to reduce the comparison to only one condition. Something like below

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("1", 1);
    map.put("2", 2);
    map.put("3", 3);
    map.put("4", 4);

    void movie() {
    int m;
    System.out.println("Choose the movie :");
    System.out.println("1.BAHUBALI\n2.SHIVAAY\n3.DANGAL\n4.AIRLIFT");
    m = sc.nextInt();

    if (map.containsKey(m)) {
        Payment();
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Choosen an Invlid option");
    }
}
```

> > Map.containsKey : Returns true if this map contains a mapping for the specified key.

So, initially we are putting the value that we are expecting from the user in `Map` object and then, checking if the actual user input is present in the object using `containsKey`. If it is then call, `Payment()` else, println some message

Comment: can you explain shortly?

Comment: @AniketJadhav Updated my answer. Kindly have a look