# Simplify static mapping of values

Tags: java, mapping, simplify

I want to simplify the given code (actually the mapping of status):

```
private static final Map<SomeStatusEnum, OtherStatusEnum> STATUS_ENUM_MAP = Map.of(
      SomeStatusEnum.A, OtherStatusEnum.OK,
      SomeStatusEnum.B, OtherStatusEnum.NOK,
      SomeStatusEnum.C, OtherStatusEnum.NOK,
      SomeStatusEnum.D, OtherStatusEnum.NOK,
      SomeStatusEnum.E, OtherStatusEnum.NOK,
      SomeStatusEnum.F, OtherStatusEnum.NOK
  );
```

to a structure like:

```
private static final Map<SomeStatusEnum, OtherStatusEnum> STATUS_ENUM_MAP = Map.of(
     SomeStatusEnum.A, OtherStatusEnum.OK,
     *ALL OTHER SomeStatusEnums*, OtherStatusEnum.NOK     
 );
```

so that only `SomeStatusEnum.A` points to `OtherStatusEnum.OK` while all others point to `OtherStatusEnum.NOK` without writing all of them in the map explicitly.

Anyone an idea?

Comment: Are you required to use a map? Why not use method like `OtherStatusEnum statusMapping(SomeStatusEnum en){
        switch (en){
            case A: return OtherStatusEnum.OK;
            default: return OtherStatusEnum.NOK;
        }
    }`? Here `*ALL OTHER SomeStatusEnums*` are handled by `default:` case. If you have many cases which should be mapped as OK you can something like `case A: case B: return OtherStatusEnum.OK;` (see [Using two values for one switch case statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16706716))

Comment: perfectly solved, it will use this approach :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that this is what you're looking for - but you can use a map with the getOrDefault function like this:

```
private static final Map<SomeStatusEnum, OtherStatusEnum> STATUS_ENUM_MAP = 
  Map.of(SomeStatusEnum.A, OtherStatusEnum.OK);
```

and then use the map as:

```
STATUS_ENUM_MAP.getOrDefault(value, OtherStatusEnum.NOK)
```