# Give different style to each element in an array React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am displaying an array like so :

```
  this.props.group.fields.slice(0,3).map((field, key)=>{
     return( 
        <View style= {styles.cardContainerStyle}>
        <FieldListItem key={key} field ={field}></FieldListItem>)
```

and the FieldListItem render method is  :

```
render(){
    let types = this.props.field.type                      
    return(<Text>types<Text>)}
```

Basically, I am using slice to display only first 3 elements and I want to style them differently.For example, I want to style the first element as a Title - bold, the second one as single line and font should be smaller and the last can be multiLine and color should be diff. Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do the following :

```
switch(key){
      case 0:
        return(<FieldListItem itemStyle={{fontSize:20,color:'black', fontWeight:'bold'}} key={key} field={field}></FieldListItem>);
      case 1: 
        return(<FieldListItem itemStyle={{color:'black', fontSize:15}} key={key} field={field}></FieldListItem>);   
      case 2:
        return(<FieldListItem itemStyle={{color:'grey',fontSize:15}} key={key} field={field}></FieldListItem>);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define custom styles in style-sheet or directly declare it inside component.

```
render() {
    let types = this.props.field.type
    let itemStyle = {}
    switch(type)
    {
        case 'type1':
            itemStyle={fontSize:10}
        case 'type2':
            itemStyle={fontSize:20}
    }
    return(<Text styles={itemStyle}>types<Text>)}
}
```

Comment: Actually, the style is not based upon the types. Types are dynamic so the value can be 1,2,3 or 5,6,7 but the in both cases style should be same for 1 and 5 , 2and 6, 3 and 7. How can i achieve that?

Comment: You can have it inside if...else or within switch also. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706716/using-two-values-for-one-switch-case-statement) for multiple condition in switch.

Answer (score 0):

Give your return element an id with a unique value, you can use `key` since you are already using it.

```
return(<Text id=`text{this.props.key}`>types<Text>)}
```

And in your style.css file, have sth like this:

```
#text1 {}

#text2 {}

#text3 {}
```

Comment: sorry , I did not undrstand your answer. I am working on react native