# Is There A Way To Restart The Switch-Statement If The User Didn't Select Something From The Case Options?

Tags: java, switch-statement

Basically The Title Question It's In Java And I'm Using NetBeans If It's Any Usefull

Tried Some Tuto's On Yt But Didn't Get What I Was Expecting

Im Basically Left With The default: break; Thing Since I Don't want to forget to change it later
The Cases Are Only Strings So It Looks Something Like This

```
case "Meat","meat"
case "Fish","fish"
```

Etc....
I Tried

```
default;
while(com!="Carne");
```

But It Seems To Give Some Kind Of Warning

Comment: `boolean entryOK = false; while ( ! entryOK) { entryOK = true; input = scanner.next(); switch (input) { case "Meat": case "meat": ... break; case "fish": case "Fish:": ... break; default: entryOK = false; break; }}`  This question is a duplicate of others, but my search ability is lacking at the moment.

Comment: Does this question and its answers help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706716/using-two-values-for-one-switch-case-statement

Comment: And please stop capitalizing every word in a sentence.

Comment: BTW be aware that using `==` or `!=` to compare strings is almost always an error - use the `equals()` method instead

Answer (score 1):

Here's a contrived version.  You will need to figure out how to apply it to your requirements. Once it find's `"C"` it will not repeat.  It works by using the default to reset the `tryAgain`  flag to `true`. Once the `do/while` loop restarts, the flag is immediately set to false assuming a match will be found.  Using `toUpperCase` negates the need for multiple strings for the same type.

```
boolean tryAgain;
String[] vals = {"a","B","c","D"};
int i = 0;
String result;
do {
    tryAgain = false;
    result = switch (vals[i++].toUpperCase()) {
        case "C" -> "Found C";
        case "D" -> "Found D";

        default -> {
            tryAgain = true;
            yield "";
        }
    };

} while (tryAgain);
System.out.println(result);
```

prints

```
Found C
```

The above could also be done as follows.  No default required here.

```
String result = "";
outer:
for (String val : vals) {
     switch(val.toUpperCase()) {
        case "C" -> {
                       result ="Found C";
                       break outer;
        }
        
        case "D" -> { 
                      result = "Found D";
                      break outer;
        }
    };
}
System.out.println(result);
```

And lastly another using `continue` as the default to skip over the latter print and break statements when nothing is found.

```
String result = "";

for (String val : vals) {
    switch(val.toUpperCase()) {
        case "C" -> result = "Found C";

        case "D" -> result = "Found D";

        default -> {
            continue;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way:

```
boolean validChoice = false;
int[] choices = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17};
int index = -1;
while ((!validChoice) && (++index < choices.length)) {
    validChoice = true; //we will override this if needed
    switch (choices[index]) {
        case 4: {
            //do something
        } break;
        case 6: {
            //do something
        } break;
        case 13: {
            //do something
        } break;
        default: {
            validChoice = false;
        }
    }
}
```

We are repeatedly getting a new choice `while` we lack a valid one or we do not get too many invalid choices. I simulate the behavior with an array of integers, you can replace the array and index with your actual way of getting the input.